# firebase function post data is null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a post using firebase functions, I am on the Blaze payment plan.
Regardless, It fails to get the posted data to the TOP level send_email function.
I haven't even got to the request call yet.
req.body returns null, and I don't know why.

```
exports.send_email = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.debug(req.body); // THIS IS NULL
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=<Omitted for security>&response=' + req.body.recaptchaReactive + '&remoteip=' + req.connection.remoteAddress;
    request(url, (body) => {
        //the body is the data that contains success message
        body = JSON.parse(body); // We ALWAYS fail here.
        console.log(body);
        //check if the validation failed
        if (!body) {
            res.end({ success: false, 'message': "recaptcha failed" });
            return console.log("failed")
        }
        if (body.success !== undefined && !data.success) {
            res.end({ success: false, 'message': "recaptcha failed" });
            return console.log("failed")
        }
        //if passed response success message to client
        res.end({ "success": true, 'message': "recaptcha passed" });
    });
});
```

I am calling the function using my angular code like so:

```
public formSubmit() {
    if (this.contactForm.valid) {
      console.log(this.contactForm.value);
      this.httpClient.post<any>("/send_email", this.contactForm.value).subscribe(d => {
        debugger;
        console.log('sent...', d);
      });
      this.formSentSuccess = true;
    } else {

    }
  }
```

The function does get called, but it seems as if the data is not sent.
All I am trying to do right now is get the recaptcha data back. then I will send the email

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you are invoking this function, and what you expect to happen with that request, other than what you are observing now.

Comment: What are you getting if you log just req? Are you using express?